# Button not triggering Controller method MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, button, asp.net-mvc-5

Create cshtml takes in the address written by the user.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

the button currently does nothing but i need it to trigger the method below

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"  />
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

Orders Controller Create method takes in attributes from the user.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Order order, ApplicationUser currentUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        order.FirstName = currentUser.FirstName;
        order.LastName = currentUser.LastName;
        order.PostalCode = currentUser.PostalCode;
        order.State = currentUser.State;
        order.City = currentUser.City;
        order.Email = currentUser.Email;
        order.Country = currentUser.Country;
        order.Phone = currentUser.Phone;
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(order);
}
```

Comment: Did you read any tutorial or a chapter from a book on how to do this before you posted your question here?

Comment: Do you have a form on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the code inside a `Html.BeginForm`

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your form in a Html.BeginForm() helper. Specify the controller and action method and the request type. The submit button works off this. 
This is a basic skill in any web application.